# Could just downloading (not opening) .tgz file infect Windows 10?

Tags: windows, virus, windows-10

Today I received some e-mail to Thunderbird. It had image attached that I clicked:

[image]

Which sent me to onedrive.live.com/download?... and automatically downloaded .tgz file. I am not even sure if the file was really .tgz or it was fake extension. I didn't open the file, but Windows still made some preview inside download folder:

[image]

Is there risk that my laptop is infected even if I didn't open the file and I just deleted it? Could I get infected because Windows made automatic preview without opening the file?

Comment: Theoretically, yes. Practically, unlikely, unless you are running an outdated version with known vulnerabilities.

Comment: You're ignoring the fact that the email could have exploited a 0day in thunderbird, or the download page could have exploited your browser. It doesn't just have to be the execution or preview generation of the file that delivers an exploit. But tbh based on the information provided it does look like a fake invoice scam rather than anything particularly malicious.

Comment: Unless you're worth a 2 million dollar exploit, then no.